# Cannot resolve FirebaseFirestore Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I followed the official firebase android guide, but whenever I try to instantiate the FirebaseFirestore, I get a "cannot resolve symbol" error. The issue is as shown below:
[image]

Before this is marked as a duplicate, I have been searching for a solution to this issue for hours now. Nothing I found online works. Below is my gradle config:
app:

[image]

root:
[image]

Is there any idea what I am doing wrong? I have tried various different plugin versions for fireStore and firebase app but nothing seems to work

Comment: Have you tried to add `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'` as a dependency right after your firebase-firestore dependecy?

Comment: @AlexMamo hey, I just tried that. It didn't work

Comment: did you add import statement `import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;` ?

Comment: Have you Invalidate cache and restart android studio ?

Answer (score 1):

it all hints for, that the artifact had not yet been downloaded...

check if Gradle isn't in offline mode; and sync or build the project once.

alternatively, run `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` from a terminal.

repository `mavenCentral()` is also rather relevant than `mavenLocal()`.

while the repository for these artifacts should be the `google()` one.

another [known issue](https://developer.android.com/studio/troubleshoot) is, that one may have to prefer IPv4, in the `gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: I am still getting this error after trying what you suggested. Any other ideas? I should also mention that I have instant app setup, so my app folders are split into app, feature, base and project

Comment: @mikeaxle this obviously is not an instant app module, else it would start with `apply plugin: 'com.android.feature'` and would have `baseFeature true` configured (which seems to add to the problem here). commonly it should download a whole bunch of jar/aar files, when syncing the project. please add the gradle output, then I possibly could tell more.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your gradle

The FirestoreRecyclerAdapter class is part of the FirebaseUI Library but not the core Firestore SDK

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try close your project and reimport it again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have missed import statement

`import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;`

[image]

Comment: That's one of the first things I tried and it didn't work. I got tired of struggling with this so I just started a new project without instant run and migrated my code. I know it was something to do with the multiple .gradle files instant run creates but I don't have time to figure it out. It would be nice to know what the issue was because I do want to use instant run in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

1. In Android Studio, click on File.
2. Then click Sync Project with Gradle Files.

Comment: Did that helped @Mikeaxle ?

Answer (score 0):

I Recently Had that Error and this are the steps that I tried, I am not pretty sure which one of these did the trick but the error was solved and I was able to utilize fireStore. These are not in any Order I just randomly continued doing these.

I hope these helps. 
Check for these

**1. Have You Installed Google Play Services and Google Repository.**

> Check for the Updated Version and install it if available.

**2. Try to Match All the Versions in the *gradle config: app* ... for eg,**

```
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.3'
```

Sync Those Files for Quite few times

**3. Clear Caches and Restart the Android Studio IDE**

> Step 1:- Go to File Menu > Invalidate Caches/Restart..
>   Step 2:-
>   Click on Invalidate and Restart on the Window that Appears
>
> This
>   will restart the project and rebuild it,      Stay calm as this can take
>   quite a time.

---

After Following These Steps all my Error were Solved and I was able to instantiate the FirebaseFirestore.

Comment: Please let me know if this helped you in any way, I know these are basics but it helped me so would like to know if it helped you too. In case if I encounter this error again in my Code.

Answer (score 0):

project build.gradle

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this problem. There is a simple solution.

1. Add this to your app Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.3.1'
```

2. Import the following statement:

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
```

Thank me later :)